# Computations question

Tags: divisibility, factoring

a) Determine the prime factorizations of 3850 and 4125

b) Find the value of d = gcd(3850,4125)

c) List all the positive divisors of d

This is what I have so far.

a) 3850: 11, 5, 5, 7, 2

4125: 11, 5, 5, 5, 3

b) gcd(3850,4125) = 11

c) How would I find this?

Comment: gcd$=11\cdot5^2=275$

Comment: gcd of 3850 and 4125 is 275?

Comment: @DanielValentine That would be correct.

Comment: If $m=\prod p_i^{r_m},n=\prod p_i^{r_n} $ gcd $$=\prod p_i^{\text{min}(r_m,r_n)}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is what @lab trying to refer you:
[image]

Now pick the primes which are in common in two numbers with minimum powers. So you get $$\gcd(3850,~4125)=5^{\color{red}{2}}\times 11$$

Comment: If we pick the primes which are in common in two numbers with maximum powers we get $lcm(3850,4125)=2\times3\times5^3\times7\times11$.(+1)

Comment: so is my answer to part b 25*11 = 275?

Comment: How would I find all the positive divisors?

Comment: @DanielValentine: Do the same as the picture tells and then consider all multiplications of primes. I mean: $$1, 2, 5, 7, 2\times 5=10, 11, 2\times 7=14, 2\times 11=22, 5\times 5=25, 5\times 7=35, 2\times 5\times 5=50, 55, 70, 77, 110, 154, 175, 275, 350, 385, 550, 770, 1925, 3850$$

Comment: why would 7 be a possible divisor of d? which is 275

Comment: would the positive divisors just be 1, 5, 11, 25, 55, and 275?

Comment: @DanielValentine: It is wrong. :) In fact according to the definition of `gcd` $d$ divide both numbers. Does $7$ divides $d$ while $d$ is free of $7$?!

Comment: @DanielValentine: Yes they are for $d$. Not for two numbers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So my question tells me to list all the positive divisors of d, won't I just be looking at 275?

Comment: @DanielValentine: As you wrote it, your question tells you to list all the positive divisors of $d$ which is $1,5,11,25,55,275$.